# Separate trace/log file per runtime and wlapp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

By default all MobileFirst logging goes into the application server log files.
As a server can have multiple runtimes and each runtime multiple applications and adapters, everything goes into a single file.
Is there a way to have separate log/trace file for each MFP runtime, adapter and/or wlapp application?

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst Platform Server uses the application server's logging facilities, so the logs and trace go wherever the application server decides to put them.

WebSphere Application Server, Liberty Core, and Tomcat, all have various (and different...) ways to configure the app server logging in ways that may meet some of your needs (like logging per-application, for example - each MobileFirst runtime is a separate "application", as far as the app server is concerned - or separating logs from different facilities into different files).  The MobileFirst Platform Server itself doesn't provide any special support for this - it just logs things, and lets the app server determine what to do with it.  I can't think of a way you'd be able to do separate logging from different WLAPPs or adapters, since I can't think of any way that the app server could identify what WLAPP or adapter a log message is coming from and separate it from others.

However, depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to extract the kind of information you want out of Operational Analytics.